# Branch creation was rejected by Git hook - bitnami gitlab

Tags: gitlab, bitnami

We are having bitnami gitlab setup, we have changed the URL from IP to https for gitlab. On post changing, we are facing an issue while creating a new branch.

Please find the error below
Branch creation was rejected by Git hook

Kindly check and help us to fix the above issue.

--
Anwar

Comment: Also, I have created a branch on the local machine and try to push the same. But getting the same error.                                                                   root@anwar-HP-Notebook:~/mfnew# git push origin teste2e
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: Failed to authorize your Git request: internal API unreachable
To https://mfnew.test.com/mfnew/mfnewv2.git
 ! [remote rejected]   teste2e -> teste2e (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://mfnew.test.com/mfnew/mfnewv2.git'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to change API call URL under this folder 
/opt/gitlab-8.9.6-0/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml

gitlab_url: http://172.14.5.7 , where as this is using for API calls.

Do not change this to any domain names, Always fix with current server IP.

now try to change Domain name URL in webserver (apache/nginx).
In your case https://mfgit.test.com  -> try to create branch over there.

Check logs for any errors in gitlab-shell.log

```
 [2020-04-03T15:48:15.004336 #21695]  INFO -- : GET http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/broadcast_message 0.01095
I, [2020-04-03T15:54:02.214780 #22130]  INFO -- : POST http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/allowed 0.03197
I, [2020-04-03T15:54:02.422776 #22165]  INFO -- : GET http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/broadcast_message 0.00863
I, [2020-04-03T17:47:18.726340 #30585]  INFO -- : POST http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/allowed 0.02535
I, [2020-04-03T17:47:18.927330 #30620]  INFO -- : GET http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/broadcast_message 0.00911
I, [2020-04-03T17:55:00.414599 #31461]  INFO -- : POST http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/allowed 0.02278
I, [2020-04-03T17:55:00.611440 #31496]  INFO -- : GET http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/broadcast_message 0.00665
I, [2020-04-04T18:12:00.693185 #2563]  INFO -- : POST http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/allowed 0.02483
I, [2020-04-04T18:12:00.885938 #2598]  INFO -- : GET http://172.14.5.7/api/v3/internal/broadcast_message 0.00933
I, [2020-04-04T18:12:01.616625 #2624]  INFO -- : Running git gc for </opt/gitlab-8.9.6-0/apps/gitlab/repositories/mfgit/mfwebv2-api.git>.
```